# Scrolling NSTableView when Dragging

Tags: objective-c

I have not had success in finding an answer anywhere, I presume it is simple but after many hours of frustration I am still stuck, so here is what I am trying to do.

I have an NSTableView set up which is populated programmatically with:

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;

TableView scrolls up and down whenever mousedown moves outside the view.

Next I set up drag & drop, which work great as long as I stay inside the current view. I use:

- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView validateDrop:(id)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation;
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView acceptDrop:(id )info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation;
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard;

This last one appears to be the crux of my problem. If it returns YES then the selected cell drags, but auto scrolling turns off. So if I try to drag beyond the table view nothing happens. Returning NO stops the dragging but re-enables the scrolling.

So how do I get to Drag and Scroll at the same time?

Comment: How did you implement the scrolling?

Comment: So far nothing other than standard functionality. This is what I am wondering if I am missing something? Without drag & drop the TableView scrolls, which is what I believe is the purpose of the NSScrollView?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize `NSTableView` can do this.

Comment: Does the default scroll-while-you-drag work? This should happen when you drag the row almost outside the visible part of the table view.

Comment: Yes, so long as tableView:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard: returns NO. But then there is no drag & drop ability.

Comment: So the answer is no? If you don't understand what I mean: Drag a piece of text in TextEdit or the Xcode editor on the first or last visible line of text (in a scrollable text). The same scrolling behaviour is default in a table view.